# Class 'PushManager' not found - Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am on laravel 4.2 and im trying to install https://github.com/Ph3nol/NotificationPusher

It installed well but I ran into the error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
Class 'PushManager' not found
```

when I ran the /push route as below:

```
Route::get('push', function(){
    // First, instantiate the manager and declare an adapter.
    $pushManager    = new PushManager();
    $exampleAdapter = new ApnsAdapter();

    // Set the device(s) to push the notification to.
    $devices = new DeviceCollection(array(
        new Device('Token1'),
        new Device('Token2'),
        new Device('Token3'),
        // ...
    ));

    // Then, create the push skel.
    $message = new Message('This is an example.');

    // Finally, create and add the push to the manager, and push it!
    $push = new Push($exampleAdapter, $devices, $message);
    $pushManager->add($push);
    return $pushManager->push();
});
```

Could I be missing a step? (perhaps declaring a provider or alias in my app.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following at the top of your **routes.php**:

```
use Sly\NotificationPusher\PushManager;
use Sly\NotificationPusher\Adapter\Apns as ApnsAdapter;
```

Routes are being defined in global namespace, **PushManager** is stored in another namespace, so it needs to be explicitly imported.

Comment: Good. Then i get "Class 'ApnsAdapter' not found"

Comment: You need to import that class as well. But I don't see "ApnsAdapter" class in the latest version of the package. The class is called "Apns". Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes. I copied the code from the getting started guide https://github.com/Ph3nol/NotificationPusher/blob/master/doc/getting-started.md

Comment: There is definitely some steps that I cannot see in the docs - defining providers? Aliases? Setting up my GCM keys? The only thing i have done is ran `composer require sly/notification-pusher`

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer, that's what they do in ApnsAdaptere readme

Comment: now `The required option "certificate" is missing.`

Comment: See the docs on how to use the adapter here: https://github.com/Ph3nol/NotificationPusher/blob/master/doc/apns-adapter.md there is your certificate option described

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87169/discussion-between-techytimo-and-jedrzej-kurylo).